# codeigniter site_url 404 page not found

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, view

I'm using CodeIgniter in localhost (MAMP) starting with the project example given with CodeIgniter itself. I want to load a view from welcome_message.php, so first of all in welcome Controller I've written

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->helper('url');

    $this->load->view('welcome_message');
}
```

then I've create the new view with a simple text. In welcome_message.php I've put

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('test');?>">Test</a>
```

(both the views are in views folder)

When I open welcome_message.php in my browser I see the link but when I click on it Test.php is not loaded. I read only

**404 Page Not Found
The page you requested was not found.**

In other project that I've seen on the web this works without problems, I don't know how can I fix it.

Comment: You need to create a controller called `Test` with a function `index` and inside it load the test view.

Comment: You're right, thank you. If you write this as an answer I'll set it as the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to check your .htaccess file. Create a new .htaccess file in the root of Code Igniter with the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Besides that your routing has to be done in

```
application/config/routes.php
```